# Would Bluetooth dongles work on my speaker that has USB port?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm looking at some USB dongles on eBay, and I was wondering if I was to buy one, i could connect to my speaker which has a USB port, so that I can play music on it from my computer without using an aux cable. Would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not, as your speaker will have no idea how to use the USB Bluetooth adapter you've plugged in.